# BASH - Copying a specific part of a file into a string

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have a textfile, lets call it Jy.dat

I want to select via a bash script the characters from 20 to 29 of line 7 and copy them into a string variable.
I have tried with sed but did not succeed

Could you please help?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed '7q;d' Jy.dat` for selecting the 7th line of the file
and `cut -c20-29` to select only those chars.

So, all togheter: `myvar=$(sed '7q;d' Jy.dat| cut -c20-29)`

Comment: This seems fine, but how do I copy it into a string variable?

Comment: `cut` is not really needed here since `sed` or `awk` can get substring also.

Comment: @anubhava: you're probably right but that was the only method I know :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NR == 7 {print substr($0, 20, 9); exit}' file
```

To copy into a variable:

```
str=$(awk 'NR == 7 {print substr($0, 20, 9); exit}' file)
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting with this OR you're trying some other command?

Comment: To copy into a string variable, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below sed command,

```
foo=$(sed -rn '7s/^.{19}(.{10}).*/\1/p' file)
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
foo_bar
<a name="menu_portlet_testbar">
$ foo=$(sed -rn '2s/^.{19}(.{10}).*/\1/p' file)
$ echo $foo
et_testbar
```